# changing file type from JAVA000064 to JAVA

Tags: java, windows

I received some files which are supposed to have .java extension and Type JAVA but they actually have no extension and the file Type shows JAVA0000664 ( This is on my Windows 7). I don't know how this happened. I want to change the file extension and type to java. Am only able to add .java extension with the "rename" option in windows but am not able to change the file type from .JAVA0000664 to .JAVA.

How can I do this?

UPDATE: All, please note that when you list the files under a folder in Windows , and see its Name/Date modified/Type/size etc, under name you will see xx.java and under type you will see JAVA file. My problem is under name it shows xx (without .java extension)  and under type it shows JAVA0000664. I can rename the file to xx.java but the type still shows .JAVA0000664. I want to change this type to .JAVA and I need help for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Windows Explorer, you can do this by opening up any folder or you can just click Start > User Name.
2. Click “Organize”, scroll down and click “Folder and search options”.
3. Click the “View” tab. Scroll down until you see “Hide extensions for known file types”, un-check this line here by clicking on the check box.
4. Click “OK” and now your file extensions will now longer be hidden.

Source:  http://askabouttech.com/how-to-show-file-extension-in-windows-7/

Comment: how will hiding extensions help me to change the file type?

Comment: The problem is that your extensions are currently hidden, these instructions are to SHOW extensions, not hide them. When you changed the file name to xx.java, Windows put the hidden extension on the name and made it xx.java.JAVA00000664

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7, you have to open your folder and search options and disable hiding known file types. Then you should be able to rename the files to .java

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-folder-options

Answer (score 0):

Try opening them in Notepad++; then use the save as feature.

Comment: Did you save it as _file_name_.java and select java source file?

Answer (score 0):

Windows understands the file type only from its extension. If you change the extension to *.java then it will be understood as java file. Therefore, it seems you or some program has messed with the windows registry of your computer.

The easiest way to reset it is by using the "open with other program..." after right clicking a .java file and change its default file type.